# Synapse SQL treating varchar variable with empty value and spaces same

Tags: sql, azure-synapse

I am having 2 tables in Syanpse SQL:

```
select employee_ID, department_id, email from AzureDW_DIatScale.[employees_withNulls2];

2,0," "
0,0,

select department_id, department_name from AzureDW_DIatScale.[departments_withNulls2];

0,
2," "
```

here as you can see email in first table is having one value with spaces and one empty value, and in 2nd table department_name is having one empty value and one with spaces.

Now if I do left outer join on  these two tables:

```
select t1.employee_ID as E_ID, t1.department_id as D_ID, t1.email, t2.department_id as D_ID2, t2.department_name as D_NAME  from AzureDW_DIatScale.[employees_withNulls2] t1 
left outer join AzureDW_DIatScale.[departments_withNulls2] t2 
on t1.EMAIL = t2.DEPARTMENT_NAME;
```

I am getting output with 4 rows:

```
E_ID,D_ID,email,D_ID2,D_NAME
2,0," ",0,
0,0,,0,
2,0," ",2," "
0,0,,2," "
```

Can anyone please help me with some official documentation or any suggestion as to why it is considering empty and spaces values same and matching 2 times for join condition.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with some sample data and used the left join from your question:

```
select t1.employee_ID as E_ID, t1.department_id as D_ID, t1.email, t2.department_id as D_ID2, t2.department_name as D_NAME from employees_withNulls2 t1
left  outer  join departments_withNulls2 t2
on t1.EMAIL = t2.DEPARTMENT_NAME;
```

**Results:**
[image]

In SQL, string comparisons are typically case-insensitive and ignore leading and trailing spaces by default.
This behavior causes empty values and values with spaces to be considered equivalent, leading to potential duplicate matches in your left outer join condition.

To distinguish between empty values and those containing spaces, you can utilize the `NULLIF` function.
This function converts spaces to **NULL** values, enabling you to differentiate them from truly empty values before executing the join operation.

The below is the syntax:

```
SELECT t1.employee_ID AS E_ID, t1.department_id AS D_ID, t1.email, t2.department_id AS D_ID2, t2.department_name AS D_NAME
FROM employees_withNulls2 t1
LEFT  OUTER  JOIN departments_withNulls2 t2
ON  NULLIF(t1.EMAIL, '') = NULLIF(t2.DEPARTMENT_NAME, '');
```

[image]